# Starting process asynchronously

Tags: camunda

I'd like to ensure that each and every Camunda process instance starts asynchronously regardless of the process definition. The [Configure Asynchronous Continuations](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/#configure-asynchronous-continuations) documentation suggests that this behaviour requires marking each Start Event with "Asynchronous Before" attribute:

> Asynchronous instantiation of a process instance is enabled using the camunda:asyncBefore extension attribute on a process-level start event. On instantiation, the process instance will be created and persisted in the database, but execution will be deferred.

Is there a way to achieve the same using `org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService` or other Java code without applying "Asynchronous Before" attribute to every single start event in every single process definition?

The `RuntimeService` exposes asynchronous methods but only for delete operations e.g. there is `deleteProcessInstancesAsync()` but there is no `startProcessInstanceById**Async**()` method.

Comment: You can configure async before programmatically by using a `BpmnParseListener`. This will save you the effort of modifying all your BPMN diagrams. See https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/process-engine-plugin/bpmn-parse-listener for an example of a parse listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [thorben's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3981961/thorben) comment one can implement a custom `BpmnParseListener` with `parseStartEvent()` method.

```
public class AsyncBeforeStartListener extends AbstractBpmnParseListener {

  @Override
  public void parseStartEvent(Element startEventElement, ScopeImpl scope,
          ActivityImpl startEventActivity) {
    startEventActivity.setAsyncBefore(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: This is for starting all processes in the async way. How to start just few of them async? Maybe to extend this function and check for process key?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic if it's just a few IMO just mark Start Event as Async Before in the process diagram.

Comment: Could you please provide some code examples on how to use and enable this functionality in Camunda SpringBoot?